# How to copy specific files to directory home/site/wwwroot in azure devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, copy

I have three deployments Staging/beta/Production and for all three i have different .env files used for each backend.
I have uploaded the three files in secureFiles in library now i want to download those files and copy file into wwwroot folder. How to Do that?

I am downloading the secureFile but not able to copy the file into right directory

Comment: May i know where is the wwwroot folder? Does it exist on your repo structure, or only on azure app service? I shared the sample to copy secure file into local wwwroot, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In DevOps `DownloadSecureFile@1` task, the secure files are downloaded to path: `$(taskname.secureFilePath)`(link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-secure-file-v1?view=azure-pipelines#output-variables)). You can simply copy with this path to target folder.
[image]

Please check the sample yaml below:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  name: first
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'test1.env'

- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  name: second
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'test2.env'

- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  name: third
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'test3.env'


- script: mkdir -p home/site/wwwroot   # crate the wwwroot folder because it doesn't exist on my repo.

- script: |
   cp $(first.secureFilePath) home/site/wwwroot           # copy the env files to wwwroot
   cp $(second.secureFilePath) home/site/wwwroot
   cp $(third.secureFilePath) home/site/wwwroot
```

I created artifact for checking:

[image]